# WS2012 RDP IP-whitelist not working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-access, whitelist, scope

I'm running Windows Server 2012 with newest updates etc. We've at all times restricted our RDP with a whitelist with IP in the Scope properties of the `Remote Desktop - User-mode` rule inside the Advanced Firewall.

For some reason, the scope has stopped working and I can't find out why. Everyone is able to connect to it, and it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I need some help troubleshooting this issue as it does not give any sense, and I can't come up with any changes made on the server which could cause this. My other firewall rules seem to work perfectly fine.

Property: Remote Desktop - User-Mode

General: Enabled -> YES

Action: Allow the connection

**Scope**

Local IP Adress: Any IP address

Remote IP Address: These IP addresses: (multiple IPs).

I even removed my own IP address from there, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the firewall profile - it should be set to `(X) Inbound connections that do not match a rule are blocked`. It sounds like this may no longer the case. Or if it is set look for other rules allowing more than they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The profile properties as metioned by Brian were correct, though I found the issue, there were an additional conflicting rule in my settings which allowed this port to be open after all with no scope.